# File uploader in php

Tags: php

I can't get a peer review where I work, I was wondering how my code was and how could it be improved.

https://github.com/lamondea/uploader

Is it a good practice to use functions in classes or should it be replaced by external function that use the object returned by the class:

```
class _export
{   
    public $nbr;
    public $file;

    public function __construct($file,$nbr=0){
        if($nbr != 0 && ($file->ext == 'jpg' || $file->ext == 'png' || $file->ext == 'gif'))
            thumbnailer($file,$nbr);
        else {
            move_uploaded_file($file->tmp_name, ($file->loc).($file->name));
            return $file->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really never used peer review and I just started using classes, so I guess the whole /class/uploader.class.php would be the important for that matter. I will add a part, but still it would be hard to choose a part since the uploader work.

Comment: Two general things about the code, 1) class name shouldn't start with "_", 2) Looks like you are doing the validation in constructor which is not good. Let the constructor just for initialization stuff.

Comment: Is there a norm about naming the classes?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if using classes is better or worse but I am starting to see files being called as functions more than a single file with function within. This is a more common upload script.

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
}
else{
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

Comment: The `$allowedExts` array is a good idea! You could use a similar array for `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` too.

Comment: Agreed, i would shorten this and say if($_FILES["file"]["type"] is in $ArrayofMetaData) or something to that affect. It would look much cleaner.